# Linear Transformer and Ideal Transformer: electric circuit question

Tags: transformer, inductor, impedance, circuit-analysis

[image]

The question is to determine k in so that no current flows in Zx. I literally have no clue how to start. If there is no current in \$Z_x\$ that would make it an open circuit, so for it to be possible the votlage across the 400-turn inductor must be equal to the mutual inductance. Is that right? How should I tackle this problem

Comment: Hint:  for there to be zero current through Zx, it must be the case that the voltage across the 30mH winding equals the voltage across the 400 turn winding.

Comment: Without the current, I can't find either voltages.

Comment: First, *which* current are you referring two?  Second, the only current that is important to this problem is the current through Zx which is specified to be zero.

Comment: Then, how can I find the voltage across the 30mH winding.

Comment: I could just give you the formula but you need to reason this out yourself.  Suffice to say that, since you know the voltage across the 120mH inductor, and you know the current through the 30mH inductor is zero, you *can* express the 30mH inductor voltage as a function of k.  For a refresher, start here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Coupled_inductors

Comment: Then I would need the rate of change of the current in \$I_1\$. \$V_s=M\frac{di_p}{dt}\$ where M=k.

Comment: OK, here's a hint.  Call the 120mH current \$I_1\$ and the 30mH current \$I_2\$.  Now, since \$I_2 = 0\$, \$I_2\$ is *constant* so \$\dot I_2 = 0\$.  Thus, *both* the primary voltage and secondary voltage are *proportional* to \$\dot I_1\$.  Do you see now?

Comment: What is the I with the dot on it supposed to represent?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_notation#Newton.27s_notation

Comment: The left transformer is a linear transformer and the right one is an ideal transformer. If I don't have the change in current with respect to time, I don;t see how they can cancel.

Comment: The voltage on the 30mh is \$ k\frac{di_1}{dt}\$. The votlage on the 120mh is \$ k\frac{di_2}{dt}+L\frac{di_1}{dt}=L\frac{di_1}{dt}=v_l\$ since there is no change in the secondary current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then, how can I find the voltage across the 30mH winding

For coupled inductors we have the following:

$$M = k\sqrt{L_1 L_2}$$

$$V_1 = L_1 \dot I_1 + M \dot I_2$$

$$V_2 = M \dot I_1 + L_2 \dot I_2$$

Now, if \$I_2\$ is constant, we have:

$$V_1 = L_1 \dot I_1$$

$$V_2 = M \dot I_1$$

Thus:

$$V_2 = M \dfrac{V_1}{L_1} =V_1 \cdot k\sqrt{\frac{L_2}{L_1}} $$

---

*The remainder of the answer was reasoned out and added below by the OP...*

Now, to find the voltage across the 400 winding:

$$\frac{V_a}{V_b}=\frac{1600}{400}=4$$
where 
\$V_a \$ is the voltage across the 1600 winding and \$V_b\$ is the voltage across the 400 winding.
We also can see that, 
$$V_a+V_b=V_1$$
$$ \implies V_b=\frac{1}{4}(V_1-V_b)$$
$$V_b=\frac{1}{5}V_1$$
But to have the current in \$Z_x\$ as zero, we need to have \$V_b=V_2\$. So,
$$V_1 \cdot k\sqrt{\frac{L_2}{L_1}}=\frac{1}{5}V_1$$
If we solve, the above equation, we get
$$k=\frac{2}{5}=0.4$$

Comment: How can I find the voltage across the 400. It must be in terms of V1 for it to cancel.

Comment: I got how to find the 400..I will add it to your answer now.